# show/hide control textbox based on combobox selected WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, textbox

I have a WPF/MVVM project in C #/FrameWork 4.0

In my view I have two ControlBox "NoRSAC" and "LieuRSAC"

```
<View:StateControlTextBox
                            x:Name="NoRSAC"
                            ReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"
                            ViewModelDataType="UtilisateurSaisieViewModel" 
                            TableDataType="TUtilisateurDataTable"
                            Tag="{DynamicResource TELEPHONE}" 
                            Text="{Binding UserVM.No_RSAC, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0" Canvas.Top="140" Width="185" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <View:StateControlTextBox
                            x:Name="LieuRSAC"
                            ReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"
                            ViewModelDataType="UtilisateurSaisieViewModel" 
                            TableDataType="TUtilisateurDataTable"
                            Tag="{DynamicResource TELEPHONE}" 
                            Text="{Binding UserVM.Lieu_RSAC, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0" Canvas.Top="140" Width="185" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Canvas>
```

And ControlComboBox "cmbFonction"

```
<View:StateControlComboBox
                            x:Name="cmbFonction"
                            ReadOnlyControlState="Disabled" 
                            IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"
                            ViewModelDataType="UtilisateurSaisieViewModel" 
                            TableDataType="TUtilisateurDataTable"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ListeFonctions}" 
                            SelectedValue="{Binding UserVM.Fonction, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="303" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Canvas.Left="97" Canvas.Top="108" />
```

I want to view the ControlBox "NoRSAC" and "LieuRSAC" when I select a particular valeure in the ComboBox "cmbFonction" and hide when it's another selected value

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the set method of the property `Fonction`, you can check the value and update another property that you should introduce in your view model and that is of type `System.Windows.Visibility`. In the following example, I call this property `TextBoxVisibility`:

```
public class UserVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Visibility _textBoxVisibility;

    public Visibility TextBoxVisibility
    {
        get { return _textBoxVisibility; }
        set 
        {
            _textBoxVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Fonction
    {
        get { return _fonction; }
        set
        {
            _fonction = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            if (value == "Value A")
                TextBoxVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            else
                TextBoxVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    // Other members omitted for sake of simplicity.
}
```

Please note that you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged (directly or indirectly) so that the changes of the property values are forwarded to the bindings that can in turn update the dependency properties of the controls in your view.

Thus you must not forget to add an additional binding to all of your text boxes in your view. Here is an example for that, the important part is the binding on `Visibility`:

```
<View:StateControlTextBox
                        x:Name="NoRSAC"
                        ReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"
                        ViewModelDataType="UtilisateurSaisieViewModel" 
                        TableDataType="TUtilisateurDataTable"
                        Tag="{DynamicResource TELEPHONE}"
                        Visibility="{Binding UserVM.TextBoxVisibility}" 
                        Text="{Binding UserVM.No_RSAC, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0" Canvas.Top="140" Width="185" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Comment: Thank you and thank you again
Just one last question: I have created the UserVM class? and I have to put where? in Model or ViewModel?

Comment: Not on your ComboBox (or other controls), only on your text boxes. When the user selects another item in the combo box, this is propagated to your view model via the binding `SelectedValue="{Binding UserVM.Fonction, Mode=TwoWay}"`. This only means that the set method of  UserVM.Fonction gets called.

Comment: UserVM is your View Model class. As you did not post the code for your view model, I just guessed that is called like this. You have to add the `TextBoxVisibility` property to the same view model class that contains `Fonction`.

Comment: There should be a checkmark on the left side of the answer right beneath the vote up / down arrows.